# How to write boost::shared_ptr as null?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

How do i make a default constructed boost::shared_ptr as a null pointer?
 Is it right to do as follows:

```
   boost::shared_ptr< ModuleStubSocket_C > socket_stub;
   socket_stub = boost::shared_ptr< ModuleStubSocket_C >();
```

Does now socket_stub is NULL?

Comment: In new C++ code, we use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. It's safer when doing overload resolution, `NULL` can overload as a numerical type.

Comment: Why don't you accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

`boost::shared_ptr` is default constructed to empty pointer, which is essentially null. See documentation for [stared_ptr default constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#Members).

Comment: you mean in code which i have written, only writting  boost::shared_ptr< ModuleStubSocket_C > socket_stub; will make socket_stub = NULL. Does the second line:  socket_stub = boost::shared_ptr< ModuleStubSocket_C >(); is not needed?

Comment: Yes, this would be enough.

Comment: ok, but if i write second line of the code also . What does that imply?

Comment: As MSalters already mentioned, it is just redundant. You create new `shared_ptr` with exactly the same constructor and assign it in the current one. The code is correct, but it duplicates itself. If you want to make pointer null _after_ it was used, assign it to `nullptr` or call `reset()`.

Answer (score 1):

The second line is redundant. It calls the same default constructor again to create a temporary null pointer, and then assigns it to `socket_stub` which already was a null pointer.

Comment: ok, this means that only considering the first line i.e boost::shared_ptr< ModuleStubSocket_C > socket_stub; is the default constructed boost::shared_ptr ?

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
socket_stub = nullptr;
```

should do the trick for `std::shared_ptr`.  I would expect:

```
socked_stub = NULL;
```

to do the trick with `boost::shared_ptr`, but I don't know.  `boost::shared_ptr` was broken in several ways with regards to null pointers, and this may be one of them.  (IIRC, `if ( someSharedPtr == NULL )` didn't work, which was considered serious enough to exclude the use of `boost::shared_ptr` in most places I've worked.)

Answer (score 0):

`boost::shared_ptr<>` is initialized as `nullptr`. But if you want to reset any `shared_ptr<>` back to pointing to `nullptr` you can call e.g.

```
auto ptr = boost::shared<int>();
// some other code doing something with ptr
ptr.reset(); // ptr now points to NULL
// you can assign a new pointer too!
ptr.reset(&intvar); // ptr now points to the memory location of the intvar variable
```